# Formating a cell based on another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell A with values of either "Cancelled" or "Completed". I have another cell B with numerical value e.g 9. I want to format cell B such that if cell A is "Cancelled", then the value of cell B is changed to remain but remains the same if cell A is "Completed"

Comment: is this an Excel question, then please put the version of Excel you are using or what ever piece of software you are using with 'cells' in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Conditional Formatting to do this (Excel 2007/2010/2013).

1. Select the cells (containing the number) next to the cells containing your status
2. In the toolbar, click on **Conditional Formatting** then **New Rule...**
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. Enter `=A1="cancelled"` in the **Format values where this formula is true:** box
   [image]
5. Click on the **Format...** button
6. Select **Custom** from the **Category** list
7. Enter `"Remain"` in the **Type:** box
   [image]
8. Click **OK** then **OK**

[image]

The cells which have cancelled next to them will get formatted to display only the word "remain" while the other cells remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this (at least not in Excel or a spreadsheet - I assume that is what you are referring to).

You can create another cell C, and modify its value depending on A and B, however what you have described requires programming cell B based on the contents of cell B and I'd be very surprised if that is possible - particularly at the technical level you appear to be at (Based on your tagging - of only "Windows 7" and "Windows")

I've not bothered to try this, but to attempt modifying C based on the values of A and B you would use an IF statement, so something along the lines of (by writing in cell C) would work - although its generally nonsensical to mix numberic and text values

```
if (A,"Completed","remain",B)
```

The line above can be read as '
If 
     A equals Completed
then 
     the value of cell C is "remain"
else
     the value of cell c is "B"

You might want to refine your question better for a better answer, including the type of spreadsheet you are using (and I suspect the part of your question which deals with remain).  I also suspect this is a "homework" question - if it is, thats OK, but you should ask it in a way that you can learn from it, rather then just trying to extract an answer.  [  I note that a cell would not be "A", it would be "A1" to define both a row and column ]